# Change hanging indent in Google Drive presentation

Tags: google-slides

I need to create a Google Drive Presentation, based on a corporate theme. For some reason, there's a hanging indent, which means that a multi-line paragraph looks like this:

[image]

I don't see any ruler like in the text editor. How can I remove the hanging indent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you position the cursor at the beginning of that line, like so
[image: cursor]

and press <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> once, the hanging lines will all align with the first line, like this:
[image]

Note: This suggests that Google Slides uses some kind of pseudo-character to represent this type of hanging paragraph indentation. If you press <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> again, all the lines will shift further to the left of your text box, suggesting that another uniform indentation psuedo-character of some kind. Neither are true characters, in that they cannot be selected or copied, so they are most likely some internal state tracked by the text box.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a text document with Google Drive, copied and pasted my text, adjusted the indentation and copied and pasted it back in my presentation. I had Google Drive extension installed in Chrome first to enable clipboard access.

Answer (score -1):

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> twice and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: To clarify, Ctrl+Shift+7 is the shortcut for "Toggle numbered list". If that's enough to clear the hanging indent then presumably Ctrl+Shift+8 (Toggle bulleted list) would work as well. So would, likely, any formatting toggle that works on a block of text.